# Will DbContext.SaveChanges include changes to a new object since it was added?

Tags: entity-framework

```
var newRock = new Rock();
context.Rocks.Add(newRock);
newRock.Hard = True;
newRock.Shiny = False;
newRock.CodeName = "Projectile";
context.SaveChanges();
```

In the scenario above, once I call SaveChanges(), will the modifications I made to the object after I added it (Hard, Shiny, CodeName) be saved? Or would I have to get the object from the database again to have a truly attached object?

I know I could always just set the properties on the new object before I add it. But doing it this way would cut down on the amount of duplicate code I would need to write.

Comment: Yes, it'll save them.

Comment: There is no difference between "attached" and "truly attached" :) `Add` attaches the object, marks it as `Added` and starts tracking its changes.

Comment: Thanks. I've had experiences with other DB/ORMs where you had to attach your object to the DB and commit that change before any other changes to the object were tracked, and I couldn't find documentation for EF stating one way or the other.